# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I got the following error:
At first, I successfully build `docker build -t name .` and started my docker `docker-compose up` (**everything went OKAY as expected**), but then I decided to check `docker images` and deleted an image which I had to force to delete
After that when I run `docker-compose up` I got the following error:

**Starting i536947_calculator_1 ... done
Attaching to i536947_calculator_1
calculator_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
i536947_calculator_1 exited with code 1**

and here are the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.14 as build
RUN mkdir /calculator
WORKDIR /calculator
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o calculator cmd/webapp/main.go

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /calculator/calculator /bin/calculator
CMD ["/bin/calculator"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  calculator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      HOST: "0.0.0.0"
      PORT: 8000
      USERNAME: user
      PASSWORD: pass
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I am wondering why this happened and for any possible solutions?

Comment: This can be because a dynamically linked library is missing from the image

Comment: How am I supposed to check what is missing and restore it?

Comment: Code looks find. `I decided to check docker images and deleted an image which I had to force to delete` sounds like you removed needed a base layer. Did you redo your docker build? Perhaps remove and repull `golang` docker image as well.

Comment: Hello, as a solution i removed all layers and dependencies and downloaded them again.
The problem is that is like you said that i have removed the wrong layer. Everything is working now as it is expected!